# Add date to email subject in elastalert2

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elastalert2

I'm using elastalert2 to alert users if the requirement is hit within the elasticsearch data. The rule that I've used is the following:

```
name: "Test email alert"
type: "any"
index: "es-test"

query_delay:
  minutes: 60

aggregation:
  minutes: 6

timestamp_field: "timestamp"
filter:
  - term:
      keyword: "ELASTALERT"
alert:
  - "email"
email:
  - "abc@gmail.com"

alert_subject: "Test Email Alert - {0}"
alert_subject_args:
    - "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
alert_text:
  '<p>
    This is a test email alert....
  </p>'
alert_text_type: alert_text_only
email_format: html

smtp_host: smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port: 465
smtp_ssl: true
smtp_auth_file: /home/smtp_auth_file.yaml
from_addr: xyz@gmail.com
```

The issue is since the subject does not have a date, all the emails get cascaded together. I have tried adding a subject_args like in the rule above but it did not work out:-

The output has subject : "Test Email Alert - "

I needed help to add a date and time to the email.